# Evaluating the line integral

Tags: calculus, integration

The question I'm working on states:

Let $C$ be the curve in $\mathbb R$ consisting of line segments from $(4,1)$ to $(4,3)$ to $(1,3)$ to $(1,1)$. Let $F(x,y) = (x+y)i + (y-1)^3 * e^{\sin(y)}j$. Evaluate the line integral: $$\int_{c} F* \,dr$$

I've never computed the line integral with four separate points before. I'm thinking that I'll need to use Green's Theorem and use the points as boundaries for integration? However I'm not even sure how to start the process. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just to be clear, does the curve $C$ include the line segment from $(1,1)$ to $(4,1)$, or is $C$ an open curve? It's not going to matter too much as the problem is easily solved in either case.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 It doesn't specify whether it includes the line segment, so I can't give you a concrete answer for that one unfortunately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**METHOD 1:**  EXPLOIT GREEN"S THEOREM

Note that $\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y}=1$ and $\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x}=0$.

On the line integral from $(1,1)$ to $(4,1)$, $\vec F=\hat x(x+1)$.  So, the integral over the three segments of interest can be computed as the integral over all four segments minus the integral over the segment from $(1,1)$ to $(4,1)$.  And that integral is trivial.  The integral over the four segments constitutes a closed curve and application of Green's Theorem is again trivial.

Let $C_4$ be the segment from $(1,1)$ to $(4,1)$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_C \vec F \cdot d\vec r&=\oint_{C+C_1}\vec F \cdot d\vec r-\int_{C_1}\vec F \cdot d\vec r\\\\
&=\int_1^3\int_1^4\,(-1)\,dx\,dy-\int_1^4(x+1)dx\\\\
&=-6-\frac{21}{2}\\\\
&=-\frac{33}{2}
\end{align}$$

---

**METHOD 2:**  DIRECT LINE INTEGRAL APPROACH

If we wish to compute the line integral over the original contour $C$ directly, we have

$$\int_C \vec F \cdot d\vec r=\int_1^3 (y-1)^3e^{\sin y}dy+\int_4^1(x+3)dx+\int_3^1(y-1)^3e^{\sin y}dy$$

The first and third integrals on the right-hand side cancel and we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_C \vec F \cdot d\vec r&=\int_4^1(x+3)dx\\\\
&=\left.\frac{(x+3)^2}{2}\right|_4^1\\\\
&=\frac{16-49}{2}\\\\
&=-\frac{33}{2}
\end{align}$$

as expected!

It might be interesting to note that this answer would not be impacted if we changed $F_y$ to any smooth function that is independent of $x$.

Comment: thanks so much! This definitely clears it up. Also, where is the (x+3) coming from here, and also, what about the point (4,3)?

Comment: ah okay. I guess I'm just a little bit confused about how we split up F*dr in method 2. Would you mind explaining that? I see that you split it up into three separate integrals but I'm not 100% sure why we did it like that? (thanks again, you're awesome!)

Comment: Well, there are $3$ straight-line segments of the original contour $C$.  The first is the vertical segment (i.e., $x=4$ and $dx=0$) from $(4,1)$ to $(4,3)$. The second is the horizontal segment (i.e., $y=3$ and $dy=0$) from $(4,3)$ to $(1,3)$.   The third is the vertical segment (i.e., $x=1$ and $dx=0$) from $(1,3)$ to $(1,1)$.  Does that help?

Comment: That was perfect, thank you so much!

Comment: @user3472798 You're welcome.  My pleasure!